# Time out while mounting samba share

Tags: samba

I am trying to mount a hard-disk connected to my WDTV Live box. The following command

```
smbclient -L 192.168.1.2 -U guest
```

gives the following output:

```
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.1]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    Expansion_Drive Disk      Expansion_Drive
    MICROVAULT      Disk      MICROVAULT
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (WDTV LIVE)
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.1]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    WDTVLIVE             WDTV LIVE

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    WORKGROUP
```

But if I try

```
sudo smbmount //WDTVLIVE/Expansion_Drive /home/ashish/wdtvlive/ -o guest,rw
```

I get the following:

```
Warning: mapping 'guest' to 'guest,sec=none'
mount error(110): Connection timed out
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I am able to browse and mount through Nautilus as well, but I dont want the drive to be mounted at gvfs.

Answer (score 2):

smbmount uses mount.cifs underneath, which can not do NetBIOS lookups, only DNS lookups. The names displayed by smbclient are NetBIOS names.

You should be able to specify the IP to use to smbmount, e.g.:

```
sudo smbmount //192.168.1.2/Expansion_Drive /home/ashish/wdtvlive/ -o guest,rw
```

or, alternatively (some servers require the netbios name):

```
sudo smbmount //WDTVLIVE/Expansion_Drive /home/ashish/wdtvlive/ -o guest,rw,ip=192.168.1.2
```

Comment: This answer solved a long-standing mystery about mount and umount hang-ups. My local network sometimes has a working domain server but a broken DNS. Adding the ip= option fixes it (at the cost of hard-wiring the IP address).